# Integrate Zoho phonebridge into my pbx system?

Tags: integration

Is there any way to integrate zoho phonebridge into my pbx system (without registering to zoho marketplace)?
I asked Zoho support and was told that they do not support integration with systems that are not registered through them.

i research pages zoho but i can't see any document about integration phonebridge